# Cant use php fopen() function in functions.php

Tags: functions

I am trying to simple run fopen() in the **functions.php**, and have also tried it in a **test.php** wordpress template file.

But it does not work. If I move the test.php file and csv file to a location outside the theme folder then it works first time.

```
function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',')
{
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return FALSE;

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if(!$header)
                $header = $row;
            else
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(csv_to_array('csv/nationality-codes.csv'));
echo '</pre>';
```

This is my folder structure in the theme file...

[image]

Any ideas why it does not work?

Comment: What error message do you get? Try the full path to the CSV file.

Comment: I agree with Steven, my guess is a path issue.